# gridview load remote image . updating view?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am using a `GridView` having image as child items.

The `getView` functions loads a default image from the application "Loading.gif" for all the child items.
In another thread I load all the images to some Bitmap type into the adapter.

Is it wise enough to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after each image is loaded ?

Or is there and alternative way to directly update the image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the technique used in ListView , where default image used in listview items. And a thread load images for list items and update the new images without `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` called.

http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-lazy-image-loader-example.html

If you want more efficient way to do this then check this out.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/ImageDownloader.html

Comment: But what if its like my current view show 4 images . the list has 100 image. And when one image is loaded I call notifiyDataSetChanged() it would load the view for 4 images . ? efficiency ...